# Does Sharepoint 2013 really have a jquery conflict with $?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

I have been working on SharePoint 2013 recently, and noticed that under variation sites, SharePoint 2013 has a java script file that defines a global variable called `$` which overwrites the jquery $ and brakes all my code. Other solutions say to wrap it with a self executing anonymous function passing in jQuery.noConflict and making the parameter name $.

http://chuvash.eu/2012/06/01/in-cmssitemanager-js-conflicts-with-in-jquery/

[http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-5-SharePoint_2013_-*JavaScript*-and-amp%3B_jQuery_big_booboo_to_watch_out_for.aspx](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-5-SharePoint_2013_-_JavaScript_-and-amp%3B_jQuery_big_booboo_to_watch_out_for.aspx)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

I was just wondering, since SP2013 has been out for years now and I never heard of this problem before, is this really a big problem or did someone find a fix for it?

I don't want to have to update all my jquery uses with with code since there is a lot of them.

Comment: There is an actual collision on the global `$` object between jQuery and SharePoint's out of the box JavaScript. They even perform similar functions (like selecting elements) but the behavior is different. Usually this isn't an issue if you wrap your code in one of the `SP.SOD` methods since SharePoint's built-in code has already run by the time jQuery gets loaded and called. The SharePoint code has a whole interface I'll let someone else describe in an answer though

Comment: Can you give an example by what you bean by wrapping code in SOD?

Comment: `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myAwesomeFunctionDefinedBelow, "sp.js")` is one example, take a look at the [MSDN SP.SOD Methods Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408081(v=office.14).aspx) for more info

Comment: If I do that, at what point do I import jquery? And how? Should I requireJS it in my awesome function?

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. I spent a day trying to figure out what was wrong on a wiki page. And I can't believe that they have made a $ function! Unbelievable. At the moment I have experienced this only on Wiki pages.

Answer (score 3):

On average there are no issues, that is why you won't see many issues posted.

Once you get deeper under the hood you **might** experience problems, but it all depends on your coding style. *and no I do not have clear examples where I burned my fingers*.
noConflict is an easy fix.

But lets face it, jQuery is something from the height of the Browser Wars.

Now (january 12th) Microsoft officially ended IE9 support why would we developers support below IE10 browser versions?

Modern ES5 (we're already on ES6 now) JavaScript can do everything jQuery does (**and faster**)

SOD was already mentioned, be sure to also fully understand
https://www.spcaf.com/blog/sp-context-dev-part-6-jquery-vs-sharepoint/
(*and the previous 5 blogs*)

My advice: do not waste time learning (more) jQuery. Learn JavaScript

Comment: Isn't the point of jquery, to simplify the code of javascript? Sure javascipt runs faster but if it means I can write much less code, then wouldn't I still use jquery? Also It has to run on IE11.

Comment: No the point of jQuery *was* to write code that all browsers support. The eco system evolved to a number of uncountable plugins that *made* life easier. Most of these plugins do not support modern 2.x jQuery. That is why I encounter (SharePoint) projects where every Add-in loads its own version of jQuery (oh what a joy for Mobile users). If you want to write less code and be ready for the future learn TypeScript (which transpiles to JavaScript)

Comment: So to future proof SharePoint environment, are you saying to completely remove jquery, and use the build in sharepoint mquery described in the article?

Comment: Yes, learn the normal JavaScript way of doing things, learn what mQuery is and may do for you. You don't have to ban jQuery, just understand its not required. I only use jQuery because I am lazy and use $.ajax() .. but even that can be done without jQuery **and with less code**, see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157139/is-ajax-built-in-in-sharepoint-online-sharepoint-hosted-apps/157148#157148

Comment: I'm still not sure about whether to switch to mquery instead of jquery. Because as sharepoint evolves and we migrate content, there is a possibility of mquery changing which would break code, or being completely dropped (an example is Microsoft dropping Full text query in SP2013). But with jquery, as long as all the code works with jquery, you can just keep using that file locally. So it would seem like jquery is more stable in long term?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167237/is-mquery-stable-to-use-instead-of-using-jquery-in-sharepoint-2013-and-higher

Comment: For writing "less" code: In fact, modern javascript does not require to write that much more code. After all, because of including the whole jquery-file which has much code, you won´t need and use, your website is much bigger in size and your browser has to load much more js-code as it needs. So, altough you write less code by yourself, it does not mean that your performance is better (because the code, you don´t write, is just written by someone else with much additional stuff, but still loaded and executed by the browser).

Comment: This is more of a religious war than a technical one. There are many opinions about whether to use jQuery, go with pure JavaScript, etc. You should make decisions based on *your* requirements, skills, and technology stack.

Comment: That's my motto, learn to develop without jQuery is the only way to keep away from religious debate. It took me 15 minutes to learn [Ajax and Promises](https://davidwalsh.name/promises) the standard ECMAscript way. And 2 hours to rewrite [iCSR](http://iCSR.github.io) and get rid of jQuery dependencies. BTW its IS a technical war when you have to develop for an environment where 10 different Apps install 5 different versions of jQuery.. and the fun starts when 2 of them deploy jQuery in the Style Library with the same name...the previous developer said "*use the jQuery noConflict*" option..

Comment: Comparing jQuery to ES6 is apples and oranges. jQuery is a JavaScript library (whch could hypothetically be coded in ES6) while ES6 is a set of JavaScript standards which amounts to syntax changes. In my opinion, jQuery still definitely saves time working with the DOM, and a more apt comparison for jQuery would be modern UI JS frameworks such as Angular or React. Also, I 100% agree with Marc.

Comment: You are a year late with your opinion.  ES6 is apples, and very tasty ones in TypeScript. People now *learning* jQuery are bananas, if you master jQuery it is just another tool in the toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

Using `noConflict` should already be a solution.

Consider also the possibility to don't use jQuery, where SP built-in mQuery could be sufficient, as very well highlighted by this article:
[SharePoint JavaScript Context Development Part 6 – jQuery vs SharePoint](https://www.spcaf.com/blog/sp-context-dev-part-6-jquery-vs-sharepoint/)

I really suggest you to read the whole article series because it's very interesting, and it also discusses `noConflict` option in part 5.

Another option could be approaching an [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) style to organize your code where, for instance using RequireJS, you could export and make available jQuery's functions, to your custom code that will use it, using the name most convenient to you.